# Multiple NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I'm trying to prepare multiple search in my CoreData entity **Recipes**. There are parameters by which I would like to prepare fetch.

**Recipes** attributes:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * difficulty;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * code; //like identifier
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * prepTime;
```

**Ingredients** is a separate entity with the list of ingredients.

**Join** entity contains **ingredientCode**, **recipeCode**, **count**.

**getArrayOfJoinDataWithIngredients** fetches **join** entity and returns NSArray of **codes** of recipes which contains some of input ingredient.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)callRecipeFetch:(id)sender
{
    NSString *predicateString = @"";

    NSArray *codes = [[NSArray alloc] init]; codes = nil;
    if ([paramController.ingredientsForSearchArray count] > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *ingredientsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (Ingredients *ingredient in paramController.ingredientsForSearchArray) {
            [ingredientsArray addObject:ingredient.code];
        }
        MainTabController *mainTabController = [[MainTabController alloc] init];
        codes = [mainTabController getArrayOfJoinDataWithIngredients:ingredientsArray];

        NSString *ingrSet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(code IN %@)", codes];
        predicateString = [predicateString stringByAppendingString:ingrSet];
    }

    NSString *diff;
    if ([predicateString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        diff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(difficulty <= %d)", paramController.diff.selectedSegmentIndex + 1];
    }
    else diff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" AND (difficulty <= %d)", paramController.diff.selectedSegmentIndex + 1];
    predicateString = [predicateString stringByAppendingString:diff];

    NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" AND (%d =< prepTime) AND (prepTime <= %d)", paramController.rangeSlider.leftValue, paramController.rangeSlider.rightValue];
    predicateString = [predicateString stringByAppendingString:timeString];

    if (paramController.categoryCode) {
        NSString *categoryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" AND (inCategory = %@)", paramController.categoryCode];
        predicateString = [predicateString stringByAppendingString:categoryString];
    }

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString];
    [resultController findRecipesWithPredicate:predicate];
}
```

The full predicateString is `@"(code IN (\n  1,\n  3\n)) AND (difficulty <= 5) AND (0 =< prepTime) AND (prepTime <= 28800) AND (inCategory = 12)"`

Now I have an error in predicate part **(code IN %@)** when I prepare NSPredicate with code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString];
```

ERROR:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable     to parse the format string "(code IN (
1,
3
)) AND (difficulty <= 5) AND (0 =< prepTime) AND (prepTime <= 28800) AND (inCategory =  12)"'
```

How to correctly make predicate with **IN** operator. Thanks for all advices.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

use `NSCompoundPredicate` for your multiple predicates, you can refer [NSCompoundPredicate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

something like this:

```
NSPredicate * andPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicate1,predicate2,predicate3,nil]];
```

Answer (score 14):

Addition to @Joshua's answer, you can also use NSCompoundPredicate for your OR operations like this.

**Obj-C  - OR**

```
// OR Condition //

NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 1"];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 2"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate1, predicate2]];
```

**Swift - OR**

```
let predicate1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
let predicate2:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
let predicate:NSPredicate  = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2] )
```

**Swift 3 - OR**

```
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
    let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
    let predicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you.

```
    NSPredicate *bPredicate;
    bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@ OR product_price contains[c] %@ OR foodescription contains[c] %@",searchText,searchText,searchText];

NSArray *filteredArray = [getObjectsFromServiceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
```