# setting filter predicate in NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I have a test CoreData app, simple employee type db and have setup a search method. Depending on the search criteria, the filterPredicate for the `NSArrayController` is selected via several if-else statements. An example of one would be:

```
  [searchListArrayController setFilterPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormate: @"(firstname contains[cd] %@)AND(hiredate > %@)", firstName, hireDate];
```

This works without any issues, but I wanted to make it a bit better for the user - they just enter data in to the fields they desire and the app will adjust the filter accordingly. So I did the following (shortened version):

```
  NSMutableString *filterString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  [filterString appendstring:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(firstname contains[cd] \"%@\")", searchFirstName]];

  if (![searchDepartment isEqualToString:@""]){
     [filterString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AND(department like[cd] \"%@\")", searchDepartment]];
  }

   [searchListArrayController setFilterPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: filterString];
```

This also works, but here is where the problem is -> filtering by date!

In my original filterPredicate, it all worked without issue, but trying it the new way does not. Here is what I've tried:

```
  [filterString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(hiredate >= %@)", hireDate]];
```

produced: Unable to parse the format string...

and

```
  [filterString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(hiredate >= \"%@\")", hireDate]];
```

produced: unrecognized selector sent to instance...

As stated before, everything works in the original format, I was just trying something new and can't seam to get the date part to work.

Any thoughts would be appreciated - thank you.

--[EDIT]-----

Perhaps I am approaching this wrong, on the search form all the fields are available. The user enters info in to which ever field is needed. All blank fields are treated as "everything", so blank name field would show everybody. A blank name field with department = "sales" would bring up everyone in the sales department.

Having all the parameters in the predicate didn't work, a blank name field gave zero results. I do not want to use ||, because I need the AND, Sam + Sales + $50,000 as an example.

Because the user selection is unknown, I thought I would build the string when the search was called - which is why I have the BIG string.

In concept this seamed to work until I brought in the date. Really new to the filterPredicate and didn't find much but Apple doc's - which is how I was setting them up. Any suggestions on a better way are welcome.

Comment: Why do you use a "big string" to format, instead of using compound predicates that would avoid you all the `\"` and all the "()"  that you have to use.

Comment: Still new and haven't used filterPredicate much, I'll research compound predicates - thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it with NSCompoundPredicate?The predicateWithFormat call does some casting that will be lost when using strings.

Comment: Thanks Stefanf, that is what I needed - works great. Put in an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16642984/2301271 check this out